# Can we capture Logout timestamp if the user closes browser or shutdown in php?

Tags: php, session, cookies, php-7.4

If it possible what be the steps?
If not what are the possible steps?
In my overall project:
I'm using session so that users session in that application is tracked if they logs out as followings

```
id|session|login_time_stamp|logout_time_stamp
---------------------------------------------
1 |xgy67sw|   date-time    | date-time
```

But if they Shutdown pc or closes browser, logout time stamp is null.

```
id|session|login_time_stamp|logout_time_stamp
---------------------------------------------
1 |xgy67sw|   date-time    | null
```

What I want is, if the users closes browser or PC how to grab their exiting timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

Maybe you will want to read these topics:

[Want to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913875/want-to-detect-browser-close-event)

[How to store log time when the user closed the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935531/how-to-store-log-time-when-the-user-closed-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to capture when a user logs out of a website. Sessions expire after a certain time period has elapsed, but there is no reliable way to know when a user actually closes their browser or shuts down their computer.